# line chart animation in r

Tags: r, animation, charts, googlevis

I have 1000's of weekly behavior paths (from 1-52 weeks).

I'm looking to explore the data visually.

Obviously if i just plot it all it looks like a huge mess - i'm wondering is there a neat way to animate a chart such that say it loops through 100 or so accounts and builds up the chart one by one with each new line getting an obvious color and then getting shaded out as we move onto the next line. Essentially showing someone the building of the very messy chart.

Here is some example code that produces the noisy chart below.

```
#####

library(ggplot2)

for (i in 1:100){
  mydf <- cbind(seq(1:52),paste('record_',i,sep=''),data.frame(rnorm(n=52, mean=10, sd=1)))
  names(mydf) <- c('week_number','record_id','spend')
  if (i==1) {
    mydfFull<-mydf
  } else {
    mydfFull <- rbind(mydf,mydfFull)
  }
}

# plot the sample
ggplot(data=mydfFull, aes(x=week_number, y=spend, group=record_id, colour=record_id)) + geom_line() + theme(legend.position="none")

#####
```

[image: noisy plot]

I guess im looking to sort of animate the building of this chart line by line.

I found there is an animation package and am also thinking GoogleVis could be useful.

Anyone any experience or suggestions as to what could be a good approach?

Answer (score 1):

The general ideas behind the animation package can be ilustrated in this example (EDIT)

```
library(animation)
ani.options(interval=1.5,outdir=getwd())
cols <- rainbow(100)

saveHTML({
  for (i in 1:100){
    mydf <- cbind(seq(1:52),paste('record_',i,sep=''),data.frame(rnorm(n=52, mean=10, sd=1)))
    names(mydf) <- c('week_number','record_id','spend')

    if (i==1) {
      mydfFull<-mydf
      plot(mydf$week_number,mydf$spend,col=cols[1],type="l",main="",xaxt="n",ylab="",yaxt="n")
    }else{
      mydfFull <- rbind(mydf,mydfFull)
      plot(mydf$week_number,mydf$spend,col=cols[1],type="l",main="",xaxt="n",ylab="",yaxt="n")
      k <- 1;
      tapply(mydfFull$spend,factor(mydfFull$record_id),FUN=function(y) {lines(x=mydf$week_number,y=y,col=cols[k]); k<<-k+1 })

    }
  }
},img.name = "anim", title = "anim")
```

look at the `animation` package for the details in order to tweak the code to meet your requirements.

Comment: great, thanks - when i run it produces the html file which has the little player and controls but it looks like the static final image and does not seem to be layering them. will look into the package detail to get it working for me. cheers.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. You need to initialize new plot at each iteration. Try it now, I edited my answer.